# After adding sharepoint layouts mapped folder the folder not there in Layouts section why?

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I was created sharepoint 2013 empty project and i was added sharepoint layouts mapped folder name is GPIntegrationLogs

But after deployed i was checked in this path.(C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS)

My folder is not there why please some one help for this Thank in advance.

My C drive : The GPIntegrationLogs folder not there after deploy the project also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had added a folder inside `layouts` folder but did not added anything in that folder under `layouts`, So sometimes it will not create folder under **15 Hive** (`\15\\TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS`).

Please add any sample text file in the folder **GPIntegrationLogs** which is available under the `layouts` folder.

You will get the **GPIntegrationLogs** folder with that text file in it inside the `layouts` folder after deploying the solution.

Comment: But why we need to add some text file in Inside the Folder hardik any idea ?

Comment: **Sometimes** the folder won't get updated in layouts folder if it is empty.